# R studio: means of variables within a regression loop

Tags: r

My task is to add means of variables in a vector. Ive ran a loop for computing 7  simple regressions based on 7 variables and successfully saved their respective coefficients in the vector.

I then try to add means of the variables in the vector, but only get NA values. What am i doing wrong? - Please see code.

```
coef.vec <- data.frame(NULL)           # create object to keep results
for (i in 2:7) {
  m <- summary(lm(data[,i] ~ data[,8]))    # run model
  coef.vec[i, 1] <- names(data)[i]           # print variable name
  coef.vec[i, 2] <- m$coefficients[1,1]   # intercept
  coef.vec[i, 3] <- m$coefficients[2,1]   # coefficient
  coef.vec[i, 4] <- mean(data)[i]       # means of variables
}

names(coef.vec) <- c("y.variable", "intercept", "coef.x","variable.mean")

head(coef.vec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. The problem is with `mean(data)[i]`. R won't calculate the mean of a data frame.  Instead, you could do `mean(data[[i]])`, which would take the mean of the i-th variable in the matrix `data`.

```
set.seed(4343)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(900, 0, 1), ncol=9))

coef.vec <- data.frame(NULL)           # create object to keep results
for (i in 2:7) {
  m <- summary(lm(data[,i] ~ data[,8]))    # run model
  coef.vec[i, 1] <- names(data)[i]           # print variable name
  coef.vec[i, 2] <- m$coefficients[1,1]   # intercept
  coef.vec[i, 3] <- m$coefficients[2,1]   # coefficient
  coef.vec[i, 4] <- mean(data[[i]])       # means of variables
}

names(coef.vec) <- c("y.variable", "intercept", "coef.x","variable.mean")

head(coef.vec)
#   y.variable    intercept      coef.x variable.mean
# 1       <NA>           NA          NA            NA
# 2         V2 -0.004929267  0.10199783   -0.01702318
# 3         V3  0.022621771  0.07819099    0.01335064
# 4         V4  0.057342413 -0.05618310    0.06400406
# 5         V5  0.003316518 -0.10555201    0.01583185
# 6         V6  0.075092932  0.02392331    0.07225634
```

Answer (score 1):

We can extract as a `vector` instead of a `data.frame` as the `mean(data)[i]` is applied on the whole data.frame and then extract the `i`th element, but `mean` works on `vector`

```
mean(data[[i]])
```

According to `?mean`

> x- An R object. Currently there are methods for numeric/logical vectors and date, date-time and time interval objects. Complex vectors are allowed for trim = 0, only.

NOTE: Posted the solution first here

-full code

```
coef.vec <- data.frame(NULL)           # create object to keep results
for (i in 2:7) {
  m <- summary(lm(data[,i] ~ data[,8]))    # run model
  coef.vec[i, 1] <- names(data)[i]           # print variable name
  coef.vec[i, 2] <- m$coefficients[1,1]   # intercept
  coef.vec[i, 3] <- m$coefficients[2,1]   # coefficient
  coef.vec[i, 4] <- mean(data[[i]])      # means of variables
}

names(coef.vec) <- c("y.variable", "intercept", "coef.x","variable.mean")
```

-output

```
coef.vec
#  y.variable    intercept      coef.x variable.mean
#1       <NA>           NA          NA            NA
#2         V2 -0.004929267  0.10199783   -0.01702318
#3         V3  0.022621771  0.07819099    0.01335064
#4         V4  0.057342413 -0.05618310    0.06400406
#5         V5  0.003316518 -0.10555201    0.01583185
#6         V6  0.075092932  0.02392331    0.07225634
#7         V7 -0.022753324 -0.05127132   -0.01667407
```

---

If we wanted to prevent the occurence of `NA` row (as the OP's code is looping over the values from 2 to 7 and not based on the sequence)

```
v1 <- 2:7
coef.vec <- data.frame(NULL)           # create object to keep results
for (i in seq_along(v1)) {
      m <- summary(lm(data[,v1[i]] ~ data[,8]))    # run model
      coef.vec[i, 1] <- names(data)[v1[i]]           # print variable name
      coef.vec[i, 2] <- m$coefficients[1,1]   # intercept
      coef.vec[i, 3] <- m$coefficients[2,1]   # coefficient
      coef.vec[i, 4] <- mean(data[[i]])      # means of variables
    }

names(coef.vec) <- c("y.variable", "intercept", "coef.x","variable.mean")
```

-output

```
coef.vec
#  y.variable    intercept      coef.x variable.mean
#1         V2 -0.004929267  0.10199783    0.02375765
#2         V3  0.022621771  0.07819099   -0.01702318
#3         V4  0.057342413 -0.05618310    0.01335064
#4         V5  0.003316518 -0.10555201    0.06400406
#5         V6  0.075092932  0.02392331    0.01583185
#6         V7 -0.022753324 -0.05127132    0.07225634
```

#### data

```
set.seed(4343)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(900, 0, 1), ncol=9))
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Solved it straight away. Also, as you can see my coding causes NA values in the first row, do you know how to get rid of it?

Comment: as you probably can tell Im new to R, so I dont quite get what you mean. My first column in data frame is dates, thats why I thought 2:7 was correct. That is row 1=dates, 2-7=independent variables, 8=dependent variable

*Edit: saw your updated code now, many thanks!

Comment: I try your updated code to get rid of NAs, I get the following error. 

Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

Also when i try to open the coef.vec table i get: "DataTables warning: table id=rsGridData –
Cannot reinitialize DataTable. For more information about this error, 
please see http://datatables.net/tn/3
"

Comment: @pjoternivotich please comment on the accepted answer.  Thanks